# How to send data from input to service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have a problem with a sending data form input to the service.
For example I have an input:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City name...">
<span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
</span>
```

And a service which is geting data for rest api:

```
app.factory('forecast', ['$http', function($http) { 
  return $http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?q=Warsaw&units=metric&mo') 
            .success(function(data) { 
              return data; 
            }) 
            .error(function(err) { 
              return err; 
            }); 
}]);
```

How can I send the city name from the input after clicking button "Go" to construct my own api link ? And then display those data in view ?
I mean something like this http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?q=VALUE_FROM_THE_INPUT&units=metric&mo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign your input an `ng-model` directive, like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City name..." ng-model="city.name">
```

Assign your button an `ng-click` directive, like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="getForecast(city)">Go!</button>
```

Finally, add `getForecast` function to your controller, like this:

```
$scope.getForecast = function (city) {
    forecast.getForecast($scope.city).then(function (data) {
        // do something with the response
    }, function (err) {
        // do something about the error
    });
}
```

For this to work you should change your service to something like this:

```
app.factory('forecast', ['$http', function($http) { 
   return { 
       getForcast: function (city) {
           $http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?q=' + city.name + '&units=metric&mo'); 
       }
   };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

your HTML :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City name..." ng-model="city">
<span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="go()">Go!</button>
</span>
```

your Factory :

```
app.factory('forecast', ['$http', function($http) { 

    this.sendAPIRequest = function(city){
            $http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?q='+city+'&units=metric&mo') 
                .success(function(data) { 
                  return data; 
                }) 
                .error(function(err) { 
                  return err; 
                }); 
        };

    return this;
}]);
```

your Controller :

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'forecast', function ($scope, forecast) {
    $scope.go = function(){
        $scope.data = forecast.sendAPIRequest($scope.city);
    };
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking a few questions, but lets just start with the "GO" to link using input. since you're using an angular factory you may want to use a controller or something:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="formCtrl">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City name..." ng-model="city">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="goToUrl(city)">Go!</button>
    </span>
</div>
```

now you want to pass that city to the url name?

```
app.factory('forecast', ['$http', function($http) { 
    var forecastFactory = {};
    forcastFactory.customUrl = function(city){
        $http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?' + city +'q=Warsaw&units=metric&mo') 
            .success(function(data) { 
              return data; 
            }) 
            .error(function(err) { 
              return err; 
            }); 
    } 
    return forecastFactory;
}]);

app.controller('formCtrl', ['forecast', function(Forecast){
    $scope.goToUrl = function(name){
        var data = Forecast.customUrl(name);
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for very fast answer, maybe I`m doing something wrong but it is not working form me, I going to show you how my app look like for now. Now its showing only one city base on static link, but I very want to do as i write ealier, So for example load first static city oraz some welcome message, then user search for city click go and the view for this city is render
Here is a view: http://pastebin.com/dWa2fQRt
Here is a factory: http://pastebin.com/YPL4b79i
And her is a controler: http://pastebin.com/ZyqZttdw