# AngularJS, How to get the value from input and place it in a factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to do the exact same thing like this guy: [How to send data from input to service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30812180/how-to-send-data-from-input-to-service) ,and I did copy/paste every offered solution, but I couldnt manage to make it work.
Here is my starting point, when I write the code like this, it works fine:

```
var town="London";
//factory
scotchApp.factory('forecastBG', ['$http', function($http) { 
        return $http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=' + town + '&units=metric&appid=bd82977b86bf27fb59a04b61b657fb6f') 
            .success(function(data) { 
              return data; 
            }) 
            .error(function(err) { 
              return err; 
      }); 
}]);


    //controller
scotchApp.controller('beograd', ['$scope', 'forecastBG', function($scope, forecastBG) {
  forecastBG.success(function(data) {
    $scope.fiveDay = data;
  });
}]);


//view

    <div class="forecast">          
        <div ng-controller="beograd" class="first">
            <p></p> 
            <p style="font-size: 130%"> City </p>
            <p style="font-size: 130%">{{ fiveDay['list'][0].main.temp }}&degC</p>
            <p> Wind: {{ fiveDay['list'][0].wind.speed }} m/s</p>
            <p> Pressure: {{ fiveDay['list'][0].main.pressure }}hpa</p>
            <p> Humidity: {{ fiveDay['list'][0].main.humidity }}%</p>
            <p style="font-size: 90%"> Min. temp.: {{ fiveDay['list'][0].main.temp_min }}&degC</p>
            <p style="font-size: 90%"> Max. temp.: {{ fiveDay['list'][0].main.temp_max }}&degC</p>
            <p style="font-size: 90%"> {{ fiveDay['list'][0]['weather'][0].description }}</p>
        </div>                      
    </div>
```

Now, I am trying to think of a way to get the value from an input field, pass that value into var town, and then refresh the view with the new info, with a single button click. The idea is to make it possible for users to search and get the info for any city available on this API.
Please help, I am gonna go nuts with trying to make this work, and I am very new to angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few parts - first you need to make your factory return a callable function that takes `town` as a param (also going to use `.then` to return a promise):

```
scotchApp.factory('forecastBG', ['$http', function($http) { 
    return {
        getWeatherForTown: function(town) { 
            return $http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=' + town + '&units=metric&appid=bd82977b86bf27fb59a04b61b657fb6f') 
            .then(function(result) { 
                return result.data; 
            }) 
        }
    }
}]);
```

Now, make a controller function to handle your click event and call your factory:

```
$scope.getWeather = function(town) {
    forecastBG.getWeatherForTown(town).then(function(data) {
        $scope.fiveDay = data;
    });
}
```

And update the view to call this method and pass in your `input` model:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="townToSearchFor" />
<button ng-click="getWeather(townToSearchFor)" ng-disabled="!townToSearchFor">Get Weather!</button>
```

Comment: Sir, words cannot express how grateful I am for this answer.